# Subviews not hiding/showing during transtion

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a function to make a view flip. During its animation, i want to hide one view and show other.

This is not working. But if i try to move this view after the transition is complete, it shows me my required result.

Below is the code i wrote.

```
func tapped() {
    if (showingBack) {
        UIView.transitionWithView(self.contentView!, duration: 1, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
            self.contentView?.viewWithTag(1)?.hidden = false
            self.contentView?.viewWithTag(2)?.hidden = true
        }, completion: { complete in
        })

     } else {


        UIView.transitionWithView(self.contentView!, duration: 1, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
            self.contentView?.viewWithTag(1)?.hidden = true
            self.contentView?.viewWithTag(2)?.hidden = false
        }, completion: { complete in
        })
    }

    showingBack = !showingBack

}
```

Comment: Try My answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043032/uiviewanimation-trantitionfromview-using-uiviewflip-animation/39047106?noredirect=1#comment65445247_39047106

Comment: Maybe you can try `alpha` property rather than `hidden` property.

Comment: Did U show your application run screen thats show your views. ?

Comment: Did the provided answers help?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, hidden is not a property that is animatable through UIView animations. I think your best bet may be to use fade, flip, etc or start dabbling with Core Animations which are much more powerful. Take a glance at the documentation for UIView animations and Core Animations.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut, animations: {
                        self.myView.frame = /* set the frame here */
  }, completion: { finished in
println("Done!")
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
 func tapped() {
        if (showingBack) {
            UIView.transitionWithView(self.contentView!, duration: 1, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
                self.contentView?.alpha = 1.0
                self.Contentview2?.alpha = 0.0
                }, completion: { complete in

            })

        } else {


            UIView.transitionWithView(self.Contentview2!, duration: 1, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
                self.contentView?.alpha = 0.0
                self.Contentview2?.alpha = 1.0
                }, completion: { complete in

            })
        }

        showingBack = !showingBack

    }
```

Comment: If this code helps you then approve it and give your vote , Thank you...